# How to convert number to byte string in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a number consisting of 3 bytes, 0x303132
How can I convert this number to a 3 characters-long string of the same value - '012' - which is the value of each of the bytes above in ASCII?
I know you can use '\x', but I don't want to hard-code the value.

Comment: the 0x header says it's a hex value, so how would that sequence compare to the sequence of 3 bytes of value [30,31,32] ? is it a made up serialisation syntax?

Comment: You don't get it. I want to convert the number to ASCII, so 0x303132 would be '012', which is equal to '\x30\x31\x32'.

Comment: I do get it. I'm saying that the hexadecimal value 0x303132 equals to the decimal 3158322, which then splits to 3 decimal values [48, 49, 50] that when are converted to ascii are NOT '012'. So i'm asking how you come by the 0x303132 value and why you expect it to translate to '012'

Comment: ah, i see now. that's just a sequence of hex value, not a hex value per se. i was misled by the 0x prefix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My one liner functional attempt (no regex, no JQuery, no lodash), `v` contains the String

```
const s = Array.from(Array((v.length-2)/2).keys()).reduce(
    (acc, i) => acc + String.fromCharCode(parseInt(v.slice(2+i*2, 2+(i+1)*2),16)),
     ""
)
```

See it in [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20v%20%3D%20%220x303132%22%0D%0Awindow.alert(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Array.from(Array((v.length-2)%2F2).keys()).reduce(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(acc%2C%20i)%20%3D%3E%20acc%20%2B%20String.fromCharCode(parseInt(v.slice(2%2Bi*2%2C%202%2B(i%2B1)*2)%2C16))%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%22%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20)%0D%0A)%3B)

Answer (score 3):

So, since the input is a sequence of hex values (hence two characters each), I'm going to use a regexp to ignore the header (0x) and extract two (valid) characters at the time, feed them into the transformation function of the `String.replace` method, that will converts the extracted value from hex to decimal and then from decimal value to ascii character

```js
input = "0x303132"
output = input.replace(/(?:0x)?([0-9a-f]{2})/ig, function (match, $1) {
 return String.fromCharCode(parseInt($1, 16));
})

console.log(output)
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about String.fromCharCode's existence. I'll use it 